# Flutter - im having a problem calling a Api List

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Im having a problem using an Api which i have a List in. When i try to show, it shows like
`[Instance of 'Source']` on screen

i had a problem like that with others data, but i was able to use a second source of call, like

`finalApi![widget.index].aspect.name`

but this one i can use only sources `finalApi![widget.index].sources.toString()`

i will show my api right below

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<FinalApi> finalApiFromMap(String str) =>
    List<FinalApi>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => FinalApi.fromMap(x)));

String finalApiToMap(List<FinalApi> data) =>
    json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toMap())));

class FinalApi {
  FinalApi({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
    required this.description,
    required this.tooltip,
    required this.order,
    required this.rank,
    required this.patch,
    required this.owned,
    required this.icon,
    required this.type,
    required this.aspect,
    required this.sources,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String description;
  String tooltip;
  int order;
  int rank;
  String patch;
  String owned;
  String icon;
  Aspect type;
  Aspect aspect;
  List<Source> sources;

  factory FinalApi.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => FinalApi(
        id: json["id"],
        name: json["name"],
        description: json["description"],
        tooltip: json["tooltip"],
        order: json["order"],
        rank: json["rank"],
        patch: json["patch"],
        owned: json["owned"],
        icon: json["icon"],
        type: Aspect.fromMap(json["type"]),
        aspect: Aspect.fromMap(json["aspect"]),
        sources:
            List<Source>.from(json["sources"].map((x) => Source.fromMap(x))),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": name,
        "description": description,
        "tooltip": tooltip,
        "order": order,
        "rank": rank,
        "patch": patch,
        "owned": owned,
        "icon": icon,
        "type": type.toMap(),
        "aspect": aspect.toMap(),
        "sources": List<dynamic>.from(sources.map((x) => x.toMap())),
      };
}

class Aspect {
  Aspect({
    required this.id,
    required this.name,
  });

  int id;
  Name? name;

  factory Aspect.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Aspect(
        id: json["id"],
        name: nameValues.map[json["name"]],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "name": nameValues.reverse[name],
      };
}

enum Name {
  WATER,
  FIRE,
  BLUNT,
  PIERCING,
  LIGHTNING,
  NONE,
  EARTH,
  SLASHING,
  ICE,
  WIND,
  PIERCING_FIRE,
  BLUNT_EARTH,
  MAGIC,
  PHYSICAL
}

final nameValues = EnumValues({
  "Blunt": Name.BLUNT,
  "Blunt/Earth": Name.BLUNT_EARTH,
  "Earth": Name.EARTH,
  "Fire": Name.FIRE,
  "Ice": Name.ICE,
  "Lightning": Name.LIGHTNING,
  "Magic": Name.MAGIC,
  "None": Name.NONE,
  "Physical": Name.PHYSICAL,
  "Piercing": Name.PIERCING,
  "Piercing/Fire": Name.PIERCING_FIRE,
  "Slashing": Name.SLASHING,
  "Water": Name.WATER,
  "Wind": Name.WIND
});

class Source {
  Source({
    required this.type,
    required this.text,
    required this.relatedType,
    required this.relatedId,
  });

  Type? type;
  String text;
  dynamic relatedType;
  dynamic relatedId;

  factory Source.fromMap(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Source(
        type: typeValues.map[json["type"]],
        text: json["text"],
        relatedType: json["related_type"],
        relatedId: json["related_id"],
      );

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "type": typeValues.reverse[type],
        "text": text,
        "related_type": relatedType,
        "related_id": relatedId,
      };
}

enum Type { OTHER, DUNGEON }

final typeValues = EnumValues({"Dungeon": Type.DUNGEON, "Other": Type.OTHER});

class EnumValues<T> {
  Map<String, T> map;
  Map<T, String>? reverseMap;

  EnumValues(this.map);

  Map<T, String> get reverse {
    if (reverseMap == null) {
      reverseMap = map.map((k, v) => new MapEntry(v, k));
    }
    return reverseMap!;
  }
}
```

i dont understand much about Api and Json, but should be some information inside.

how i tried:

```
ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: finalApi![widget.index].sources.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
   return Text(finalApi![widget.index].sources.toString());
  },
 ),
```

Comment: need to saw the json data

Comment: Check how you call API functions and their return types

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `listview` is on `sources`, so if you want to show sources you need use its index on it. try this:

```
ListView.builder(
   shrinkWrap: true,
   itemCount: finalApi![widget.index].sources.length,
   itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      return Text(finalApi![widget.index].sources[index].text);//<--- change this
  },
 ),
```

Comment: was it what you want? @yuuu

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mistaken.
For example, you want to display the "text" of "Source".
Why don't you use Text(finalApi![widget.index].sources.text);